# Redirects on htaccess

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

i have Wordpress website that need to redirect many pages to new pages.

i trying to do that with Regex but it's not working.

the URLs look like this:

> http://www.my-domain.com/Controls/ni.asp?dzq4/6y-20150404022609-7.html
>
> http://www.my-domain.com/Controls/ni.asp?dzq4/6j-20150404185005-940.html

Regex on htaccess:

```
Redirect ^(.*)/Controls/ni.asp.* /
```

any help please.

Comment: Redirect directive doesnt support Regex.

Comment: Even if i try to do this without Regex its not Redirect it.
example: Redirect /Controls/ni.asp?dzq4/6y-20150404022609-7.html /ToHomePage.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular `Redirect` does not support regexes. However you can use [RedirectMatch](http://www.askapache.info//2.3/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch).

> This directive is equivalent to Redirect, but makes use of regular expressions, instead of simple prefix matching. The supplied regular expression is matched against the URL-path, and if it matches, the server will substitute any parenthesized matches into the given string and use it as a filename.